# How can I count the number of rows in multiple datasets, group them by one column (month), in a Select statement in Bigquery?

Tags: join, select, count, google-bigquery

I have 5 tables that all have two columns, month and a list named either one, two, three, etc.

Example for dataset1 is columns: month and one

| month | one |
| --- | --- |
| 2021.06 | 8766 |
| 2021.06 | 9778 |
| 2021.05 | 987 |
| 2021.02 | 97808 |
| 2021.02 | 76 |

What I want to do is to count all the rows in column one, grouped by the month column. I want to do this for all the dataset (count the two, three, four and five columns).

The result should be (using the numbers for column one from above, and some random numbers for the other columns):

| month | one | two | three | four | five |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.06 | 2 | 8 | 4 | 3 | 7 |
| 2021.05 | 1 | 7 | 5 | 4 | 6 |
| 2021.04 | 0 | 6 | 6 | 5 | 5 |
| 2021.03 | 0 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 4 |
| 2021.02 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 7 | 3 |

I have tried to use the following, but it seems to hang, never ending the query.

```
select 
one.month,
COUNT(one) AS one,
COUNT(two) AS two,
COUNT(three) AS three,
COUNT(four) AS four,
COUNT(five) AS five
from dataset1 1
LEFT JOIN dataset2 2 ON 2.month = 1.month
LEFT JOIN dataset3 3 ON 3.month = 1.month
LEFT JOIN dataset4 4 ON 4.month = 1.month
LEFT JOIN dataset5 5 ON 5.month = 1.month
GROUP BY 1.month, 2.month, 3.month, 4.month, 5.month
```

Comment: I think you should create a sub query to group by the month column in each table first, then you can left join 5 tables. Because when you join raw data from 5 columns, it means that BQ must join number of rows in table 1 multiples the number of rows in tables 2 and so on to table 5. It is huges number and makes BQ hang. With group by month, it reduces alot of nunber of rows when joins 5 tables.

Comment: Can you show me how you would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select *, 'one'   col from table1 union all 
  select *, 'two'   col from table2 union all 
  select *, 'three' col from table3 union all 
  select *, 'four'  col from table4 union all 
  select *, 'five'  col from table5 
)
pivot (count(one) for col in ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'))
# order by month
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach with two tables. If it works, you can scale to 5 tables

```
with gr1 as (
select month, count(one) as one from dataset1
),
gr2 as (
select month, count(two) as two from dataset2
)
select gr1.month, one,two from gr1 left join gr2 on gr1.month = gr2.month
group by gr1.month
```